# webpack script running in infinity loop in react project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

lastly I change the rendering of my react project to server side rendering.
The big issue was how do I add my SCSS files to the my project (converting to CSS).
The current status is that everything pretty much working.
There is one issue that i can't handle. I have webpack script for the client side rendering (in order to enable java script) that keep running on infinity loop even if nothing change (I add "--watch", but nothing supposed to change.

webpack files below:
webpack.client.js

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const baseConfig = require('./webpack.base');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const cssConfig = require('./webpack.cssConfig');


const config = {
//Tell webpack the root file of our server application
entry: './src/client/client.js',

//Tell webpack whre to put the output file
// that is generated
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
},
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets: [
            'react',
            'stage-0',
            ['env', { targets: { browsers: ['last 2 versions']}}]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = merge(baseConfig, config);
```

webpack.client.js

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CSSExtract = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');


module.exports = {
//Tell webpack to run babel on every file it runs trough
module: {
    rules: [
        {   
            test: /\.js?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            options: {
                presets: [
                    'react',
                    'stage-0',
                    ['env', {targets: {browsers:['last 2 versions']}}]
                ]
            }
        },
            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: CSSExtract.extract({
                  use: [
                    {
                      loader: 'css-loader',
                    },
                    {
                      loader: 'sass-loader',
                    }
                  ]
                })
              }]
            },
            plugins: [
              CSSExtract
            ]
  };
```

And this is what happened when i start to run the script "dev:build-client": "webpack --config webpack.client.js --watch"

[image: Start running the script]

and so one keep looping every two seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems to be looping over the public/styles repeatedly, I can't be sure but it's possible your Webpack is watching the public directory, try changing your output to this:

```
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/public'
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Lloyd